# Замена строки в файле

Tags: c#

У меня есть текстовый файл. В этом файле нужно заменить одну строку на другую. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Язык C#.

Answer (score 1):

Читай весь файл или его часть, в которой нужно заменить текст, в строку, изменяй строку и записывай обратно в файл.
 Ты не написал, как именно тебе нужно заменить строку? По номеру? Замена подстроки? Если замена, то нужно использовать метод Replace.

Comment: Т.е. мне надо считать всё в одну строку и потом в ней заменить и опять записать?

Comment: Да, но если файл большой, а заменить надо только в какой-то его части, то можно прочитать только эту часть файла и записать в неё, но с этим придётся повозиться. Поэтому, если файл небольшой, читай весь файл, работай со строкой и записывай обратно в файл.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
/// Replaces text in a file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filePath">Path of the text file.</param>
/// <param name="searchText">Text to search for.</param>
/// <param name="replaceText">Text to replace the search text.</param>
static public void ReplaceInFile( string filePath, string searchText, string replaceText )
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( filePath );
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();

    content = Regex.Replace( content, searchText, replaceText );

    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( filePath );
    writer.Write( content );
    writer.Close();
}
```

[C# Search / Replace in Files](http://www.csharp411.com/searchreplace-in-files/)